# 3 Months date Interval Looping

Tags: php, loops, date, intervals

I want to loop month in 3 months interval, see code below:

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
$date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime("$i*3 month"));
echo "$date"."<br>";
}
```

but am getting the below Result:

```
01-01-1970
01-01-1970
01-01-1970
```

I want to achieve below Result:

```
19-03-2022
19-06-2022
19-09-2022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generateDates(string $startDate, int $count): array {
 $date = new DateTime($startDate);
 $dates = [ $date->format('d-m-Y') ];
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    $dateTime = $date->add(new DateInterval('P3M'));
    $dates[] = $dateTime->format('d-m-Y');
  }
  return $dates;
}

$result = generateDates('2022-03-19', 8);

print_r($result);   // This will print:

// Array
// (
//     [0] => 19-03-2022
//     [1] => 19-06-2022
//     [2] => 19-09-2022
//     [3] => 19-12-2022
//     [4] => 19-03-2023
//     [5] => 19-06-2023
//     [6] => 19-09-2023
//     [7] => 19-12-2023
// )
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas.j for trying to help out, when I run the code you provided I notice the third row is not following the sequence. kindly look @ it again plz

Comment: @vascoder: I changed the code a few minutes ago because I saw that too. So please try it again with the current code.

Comment: Thanks alot @lukas.j . working perfectly... I so much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that `"$i*3 month"` won't do the calculation `*3` so this will evaluate to `"1*3 month"` which is not understandable by [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). In order to fix this you have to do the calculation then the concatenation (instead of a direct interpolation) such as:

```php
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
    $date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($i * 3 . " month"));
    echo "$date"."<br>";
}
```

You could enhace this, in fact [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) has a second parameter that allows you to specify a base timestamp:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    $date=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($i * 3 . " month", strtotime('2022-03-19')));
    echo "$date"."<br>";
}
```

[`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) may not be the best choice for this. I guess what you ultimately want to use is a combination of [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and, maybe, [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Comment: Thanks @homer this is very helpful. I appreciate